# When $f^{(n)}\to g$ uniformly?

Tags: analysis, uniform-convergence

Let $f\in C^\infty([0,1])$ and consider the sequence $$f_n=f^{(n)}$$

where $f^{(n)}$ denote the derivative of order $n$ of $f$. My question is: What is a necessary condition to impose on $f$, such that $f_n$ converges uniformly to some $g\in C([0,1])$, i.e. $\|f_n-g\|_\infty\to 0$?

I could find some examples that maybe can help.

I - If $f$ is a polynomious, then $f_n\to 0$,

II - If $f(x)=e^{\lambda x}$, then $f_n\to 0$ if $\lambda\in [0,1)$ and $f_n\to f$ if $\lambda =1$.

Thank you

Comment: In your example II, if $\lambda \in (0,1)$, the convergence to 0 is pointwise, but not uniform. And in I, the derivatives are not well-behaved at all until they become identically 0. Do you have any nontrivial examples of uniformly converging derivatives? I can't think of any. **Edit**: I think $x^{1/2}$ on $[1,\infty)$ may work, and lots of other functions with rational exponents.

Comment: I think that if these converge uniformly then g is $C^{\infty}$ and also $g^{(n)} = g$, so the only possible functions $g$ are $e^x$ and $0$

Comment: @mm-aops, I'm asking uniformly convergence only in the space of continuous functions, hence, the limit does not need to be in $C^\infty$

Comment: @EricTressler, I think that the convergence is uniformly, in fact, we have that $|\lambda^n e^{\lambda x}|\leq \lambda ^n e^\lambda$, which implies uniformly convergence. Am I wrong?

Comment: you're asking for uniform convergence of the sequence of functions $g_n := f^{(n)}$ to a function $g$. they're all differentiable and their derivatives also converge uniformly to some function $h$ (= $g$ in our case, not important tho). I'm saying this implies that $g$ is differentiable and $g^{'} = h$

Comment: You are right @mm-aops, now I saw it, so when I ask uniformly convergence of $f_n$, also I am asking uniformly convergence of it's derivatives.

Answer (score 1):

Assume that $f^{(n)}\to l$ uniformly on $[0,1]$. Then there is a constant $M$ such that for each $n$ and $x\in [0,1]$, $|f_n(x)|\leqslant M$. Conversely, this conditions implies convergence of $(f^{(n_k)},k\geqslant 1)$, where $n_k\uparrow \infty$.

We assume that $f^{(n)}\to l$ uniformly on $[0,1]$. Using 
$$f^{(n)}(x)-f^{(n)}(0)=\int_0^xf^{(n+1)}(t)\mathrm dt,$$
and an argument of dominated convergence, we get 
$$l(x)-l(0)=\int_0^xl(t)\mathrm ,dt$$
hence we get a nice expression for the candidate $l$.

Comment: we got it in the comments, the only possible functions are $e^x$ and $0$ but the question still remains if all we can say are the 'usual' uniform convergence criteria or something more. I suppose much more, because the sequence is pretty special, it's not just 'some' function, those are $n$-th derivatives of some smooth function. if we could restrict ourselves to $f$ being analytic around $0$ then it would be easy, but I'm not sure if it's even true that f has to be analytic. that's a nice question, I'll give it a try on Monday if it's not done by then

Comment: Very interesting. Do you think we can classify the functions $f$ such that $f_n\to 0$ or $f_n\to e^x$.?